What technology becomes possible with a metal that resists force?
In my setting, there is a metal that is 'reversed', to where it reacts opposite to the forces applied to it. As in, pushing it causes it to move towards you rather than away from you, or an explosion causing it to fly towards the center of the blast. This anti-impact, antigravity miracle material is what allows the setting's spacecraft to function. Because this metal essentially acts as negative weight, the average spacecraft can weigh almost nothing. The only requirement is that normal metal outweighs the reversed metal so that the object can still be moved. Acceleration becomes more difficult, but not impossible, and there are other in-universe explanations for FLT travel that I won't go into.
What other devices are possible with this metal?
I have some ideas already. In the military, weapons can be made lighter and experience less recoil. In construction, buildings can be made absurdly tall, and other construction equipment made lighter. It influences safety, freight and trade, all sorts of things.
What devices would you create with this material?

"it reacts opposite to the forces applied to it" isn't this Newton's third law? To each action correspond a reaction of the same intensity and opposite direction.

I foresee problems with shaping or even heating this metal in order to work it.

Hello @Ekulnagrom, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. For future reference, please be aware that we discourage brainstorming questions and Stack Exchange prohibits open-ended questions, especially those that lead to every answer having equal value. You can ask anything you want in [chat] (e.g. The Factory Floor), but here on Main the model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer and you're obligated to ask with the expectation of picking a best answer even if you don't. Which means if you can't explain how you'll do that, the question isn't appropriate here.

Please explain what is the exact meaning of the ambiguous phrase "reacts opposite to the forces applied to it". [Edit] the question to clatrify this. For the moment I am voting to close the question because it requires clarification.

I'll clarify the 'react opposite to force'. Thank you for pointing out the confusing wording.

Negative mass will absolutely positively blow up your setting if applied with consistent physics. Sorry, but that's the facts. I would suggest putting the physics in a black box technology and forgetting about them, then attempting consistent engineering, instead: "I  have a nearly massless building material as strong as steel, what can I do with it?" (As a question for yourself or a forum where such Qs are on topic, unfortunately not this one.)

Thank you for the feedback. Sorry for asking an inappropriate question. I'll keep similar questions elsewhere from now on.

why haven't the anti-grav metal flied off to space?

also, what about heat? Heat is just microscale movement via molecular forces. If this metal reverses cooling into heating, it would cook the planet: the moment this metal touches anything colder than it, it will heat up, making the difference greater, heat up more, runaway effect until energy approaches infinity.

This question is way too broad asking for "What other devices are possible with this metal?" and "What devices would you create with this material?" would be soliciting opinions. Please narrow the question and ask something that's not opinion-based. (You would also need to clarify what it is you're asking as at present it's unclear what you mean.)

Per usual when you have something that breaks the laws of physics:
Unlimited Energy
If you can create a dipole with positive and negative weight (as implied by the fact that you can have both types of metal on a spacecraft), you have a rotor that will accelerate indefinitely in a gravitational field (ie. anywhere in the known universe).
This can be used to generate energy.  It requires no fuel, and violates conservation of momentum, but you already have a massive violation of physics in the description of the metal itself, so where there's one, there's lots more.

Assuming negative weight means negative mass, it doesn't violate conservation of energy or momentum, because the negative part has ... negative energy, and negative momentum relative to the other bit.  Which doesn't mean it isn't preposterous. :)

I'm struggling to visualize how it would allow for infinite energy. If you e.g have a rod that is half normal matter and half negative weight matter, with a central pivot, all you've really done is shift the point of equilibrium by 90°, such that the bar remains in a vertical position rather than a horizontal one.

You've already thought of using it for making objects lightweight by simply saying "anti-gravity material" which I think is cool. If this material is literally "reacts opposite to any force" then you have massive technological implications beyond just "infinite energy"
Here are some things you didn't mention...
Anti-force only applications, beyond just "make it lightweight"

Highly effective sound proofing: It reacts opposite to sound waves.
Anti-impact PPE: A material that would be strengthened by impact would be great in armor, it would also be very likely used in protective helmets for construction sites, etc.
Better Robotic applications: You would have unique movement options and possibly more efficient designs (not that power efficiency is critical with infinite power)
Furniture: Places to sit that become "firm" when sat on, Anvils that "hit both sides" of a material, etc.
Crash Impact systems: It would be possible to reduce the momentum from things like vehicle impacts, etc. resulting in less damage and harm.
Fastening devices: Seatbelts that get "more tight" when needed, climbing equipment that if you fall is suddenly even more closed and secure...
Tension resistant materials: A rope for climbing that is smaller and lighter, but if you fall will catch you, a fishing line that is harder to snap, etc (The fishing line wouldn't give you extra help to pull it in)
Self adjusting automotive components...
Packaging that protects it's contents...
Possible prosthetics that are more "natural" in how they respond because they are not a "dead" weight.
Seals and gaskets would be able to "push" against what they are trying to prevent from going through.
Inverse Battering Ram: FBI PUSH (to PULL) TO OPEN UP
Bridges would hold larger loads...
You could mix it into textiles, a shirt that is "pressed" against your skin always.

And on and on. Your question is open ended... this list is endless. Also yes, infinite power in many different ways.
I limited my list to force only, if it reacts opposite to heat or other forces... oh boy ..
I think it would insta-sink a boat, right?
Edit:

Mount a magnet on the front, put a magnet pulling on that first magnet, the magnet will pull on the material, the material will push on the magnet (instead of resisting). Presto the magnet in front of the car now works.


Thank you! I wouldn't have ever thought about seals, tension resistance, etc. You've given me a lot to think about, thank you.

Happy to help, lucky that I got in, the topic was so broad that the question was borderline against the rules.
